# How to construct reverse btree?

Tags: algorithm, nlp, b-tree, wildcard-expansion

I was following this web page https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/wildcard-queries-1.html for learning wild-card queries.

But, not able to understand how a  reverse B-tree on the dictionary will look like.

For example if I have a Btree like this:
[image]

**

> How to construct a reverse Btree based on this btree?

**

Answer (score 1):

A Reverse B-Tree would just be the regular B-Tree data structure constructed on the Reversed string.

The prefix queries are slow, one of the ways to handle the leading wildcard queries is to construct a reverse Tree (with all the strings reversed), reverse the query too and then search it like a normal trailing wildcard query which are much faster as they have to enumerate restricted domain.

(Consider the string Lemon) For example `'Le*'` you traverse through L, then e and then enumerate all possibilities. If you have stored a reverse tree (where Lemon becomes nomeL) then a query like `'*mon'` which is a prefix query can be altered (reversed) to `'nom*'` which becomes a suffix query and can be answered in better running time complexity.

From more of a practical standpoint, Search Engines like Solr uses a similar technique to serve the leading wildcard queries. Performance improves at the expense of a higher space complexity (Space/Time tradeoff). For more information you can check Solr ReversedWildcardFilterFactory.

Comment: Hi, thanks for this anger but its already explained by stand ford page. I was asking how to construct a reverse btree.